# How do I use AWS CloudFront to cache static content that is being stored in an AWS S3 bucket and being served by an NGINX web server?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently storing my static files for a Flask web app in an AWS S3 bucket, that is being proxy_passed to an NGINX web server that serves the files to the user. I'm thinking of browser caching some of the static files directly through NGINX but I was thinking that introducing a CDN like CloudFront in front of the S3 bucket would help improve performance. Is this a feasible caching strategy or an over-complication of caching?

Comment: Putting CloudFront in front of an S3 bucket is a common use case to improve performance, particularly if your viewers are not located near where your NGINX server is hosted.

Comment: Do you know how to config Nginx and Cloudfront so that CloudFront caches statics for a certain amount of time and then goes back to the origin server when the time on the cache expires?

Comment: Setup Cache Policies in CloudFront where you can configure cache timing automatically per route (called "Cache Behavior"), and/or send the Cache-Control header out of Nginx if you'd like more granular control over the expiry of each request. More on cache policies here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-the-cache-key.html